# Error in plot.nn: weights were not calculated

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I've gotten an error message when attempting to plot a neural network. I was able to run the code fine at first then it stopped. I do not get an error message when the neuralnet() function is run. Any help would be appreciated. I predicting the loan default.

```
library(neuralnet)
library(plyr)

CreditCardnn <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/621-Group2/Final-Project/master/UCI_Credit_Card.csv")


#Normalize dataset
maxValue <- apply(CreditCardnn, 2, max)
minValue <- apply(CreditCardnn, 2, min)

CreditCardnn <- as.data.frame(scale(CreditCardnn, center = minValue, scale = maxValue - minValue))

#Rename to target variable
colnames(CreditCardnn)[25] <- "target"


smp <- floor(0.70 * nrow(CreditCardnn))
set.seed(4784)

CreditCardnn$ID <- NULL
train_index <- sample(seq_len(nrow(CreditCardnn)), size = smp, replace = FALSE)

train_nn <- CreditCardnn[train_index, ]
test_nn <- CreditCardnn[-train_index, ]

allVars <- colnames(CreditCardnn)
predictorVars <- allVars[!allVars%in%'target']
predictorVars <- paste(predictorVars, collapse = "+")
f <- as.formula(paste("target~", predictorVars, collapse = "+"))

nueralModel <- neuralnet(formula = f, hidden = c(4,2), linear.output = T, data = train_nn)

plot(nueralModel)
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Error in plot.nn(nueralModel) : weights were not calculated
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before the error you report, most probably you also got a *warning*:

```
# your data preparation code verbatim here
> nueralModel <- neuralnet(formula = f, hidden = c(4,2), linear.output = T, data = train_nn)
Warning message:
algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax
```

This message *is* important, effectively warning you that your neural network did not converge. Given this message, the error further downstream, when you try to plot the network, is actually expected:

```
> plot(nueralModel)
Error in plot.nn(nueralModel) : weights were not calculated
```

Looking more closely into your code & data, it turns out that the problem lies in your choice for `linear.output = T` in fitting your neural network; from the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/neuralnet/versions/1.33/topics/neuralnet):

> **linear.output**       logical. If act.fct should not be applied to the output neurons set linear output to TRUE, otherwise to FALSE.

Keeping a linear output in the final layer of a neural network is normally used in regression settings only; in classification settings, such as yours, the correct choice is to apply the activation function to the output neuron(s) as well. Hence, trying the same code as yours but with `linear.output = F`, we get:

```
> nueralModel <- neuralnet(formula = f, hidden = c(4,2), linear.output = F, data = train_nn) # no warning this time
> plot(nueralModel)
```

And here is the result of the `plot`:

[image]

Comment: I did not get that warning. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing stepmax. Ex. set stepmax = 1e6 or higher. It takes longer time for higher stepmax but you can try:

nueralModel <- neuralnet(formula = f, hidden = c(4,2), linear.output = F, data = train_nn, stepmax = 1e6)